# Deducing template parameter in lambda function and its result

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda

Coming from Java language as my primary I find it hard to implement a generic function using typed parameters and lambda function.
Here is my sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}

enum class ReturnCode {
    OK,
    INTERNAL_ERROR
};

class SqlException : public exception {
private:
    int errorCode;
public:
    SqlException(int errorCode) : errorCode(errorCode) { }

    virtual const char *what() const throw() {
        return "SqlException";
    }
};

template<typename R>
class ResultWithReturnCode {
private:
    ReturnCode returnCode;
    R *result = nullptr;

public:
    ResultWithReturnCode(const ReturnCode &returnCode, R &result) : returnCode(returnCode) {
        this->result = new R(result);
    }

    ResultWithReturnCode(const ReturnCode &returnCode) : returnCode(returnCode) { }

    virtual ~ResultWithReturnCode() {
        delete result;
    }

    const ReturnCode &getReturnCode() const {
        return returnCode;
    }

    R getResult() const {
        return R(*result);
    }
};

template<typename F, typename R>
ResultWithReturnCode<R> executeWithResult(F &lambda) {
    try {
        return lambda();
    } catch (SqlException &e) {
        return ResultWithReturnCode<R>(ReturnCode::INTERNAL_ERROR);
    }
}

ResultWithReturnCode<string> fetchDummyData() {
    auto operation = []() {
        //perform a DB operation here
        string result = "dummy_result";
        return ResultWithReturnCode<string>(ReturnCode::OK, result);
    };

    return executeWithResult(operation);
}
```

The error I'm getting:

```
prog.cpp: In function 'ResultWithReturnCode<std::basic_string<char> > fetchDummyData()': prog.cpp:70:39: error: no matching function for call to 'executeWithResult(fetchDummyData()::<lambda()>&)'
     return executeWithResult(operation);
                                       ^ prog.cpp:55:25: note: candidate: template<class F, class R> ResultWithReturnCode<R> executeWithResult(F&)  ResultWithReturnCode<R> executeWithResult(F &lambda) {
                         ^ prog.cpp:55:25: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed: prog.cpp:70:39: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'R'
     return executeWithResult(operation);
                                       ^
```

I see that the problematic part is deduction of the template `R`, but I have no idea how to resolve it. 
Is my approach correct or maybe I should be using some other solution here?

Comment: Nothing to do with the question, but a quick tip: you probably don't need to allocate a `Result` on the heap in `ResultWithReturhCode`. Just use a plain `Result` member variable, and that way you can get rid of your custom copy constructor and destructor -- the compiler-provided defaults will be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could exchange the template parameters to this

```
template<typename R, typename F>
```

and then add the template parameter explicitly:

```
return executeWithResult<string>(operation);
```

If you don't switch the template parameters you'll always have to write the argument that could've been deduced implicitly *explicitly*.

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution I have chosen as further implementation will be easier to read and maintain.

Answer (score 2):

#### Option #1

```
template <typename F>
auto executeWithResult(F& lambda)
    -> decltype(lambda())
{
    try {
        return lambda();
    } catch (SqlException& e) {
        return { ReturnCode::INTERNAL_ERROR };
    }
}
```

[**DEMO 1**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1623efbd3e7acbf0)

#### Option #2

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct GetResultType;

template <typename R>
struct GetResultType<ResultWithReturnCode<R>>
{
    using type = R;
};

template <typename F
        , typename R = typename GetResultType<typename std::result_of<F&()>::type>::type>
ResultWithReturnCode<R> executeWithResult(F& lambda)
{
    try {
        return lambda();
    } catch (SqlException& e) {
        return ResultWithReturnCode<R>(ReturnCode::INTERNAL_ERROR);
    }
}
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/09dccc0c134b4e24)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to help the compiler by using a `decltype(operation)` and `string` as the template parameters:

```
return executeWithResult<decltype(operation), string>(operation);
```

The parameter that the compiler can't deduce is actually `string`, so you will have to provide it yourself. Your template parameters order looks a little non-intuitive too. If you switch them around, as the other answers suggest, not only you will be able to only explicitly provide the `string` parameter, but you will also make your code easier to read.